# What is the most recent cx_Oracle version that supports Oracle client 10.2.0?

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

Scenario:

- An enterprise application that needs to get data from a very old Oracle database, running version 8.1.7
- According to the Oracle client/server support matrix, client version 10.2.0 is the latest that supports server 8.1.7
- The software stack is python/sqlalchemy/cx_Oracle.

Question:

- What is the most recent version of cx_Oracle that can be built against the 10.2.0 client libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Found the info in the [release notes](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/release_notes.html#version-5-3-march-2017):

> Version 5.3 (March 2017)
>
> ...
>
> Dropped support for Oracle clients earlier than 11.2.
>
> ...

So I suppose the most recent version that supports client 10.2.0 is cx_Oracle 5.2.1.